# How to use custom table for authentication/login in laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-7

I want to use my own created custom table 'matchingdbs' it contains two varchar fields 'Voucher' and 'Product' I want to use them for login instead of laravel existing table users and email and password field in laravel7 I am searching my answer from last 7 hours but I haven't seen any accurate information/detail yet

Comment: So this is like a "backdoor authentication", for instance someone has a magic link in an email or types something into a form? Is it reusable or does it expire? Is it tied to a single user or can a voucher be shared? My first instinct would be to have a route that handles this and then "upgrades" the user to a true native user. So the user clicks a link, you say "Welcome, please create a password if you want to come back"  and if they don't you just assign something from rand, call the voucher their username (or ask for it or an email) and then log them in.

Comment: basically it is an automatic voucher redemption system where this voucher code and prdouct item code is used to sign in to the system and voucher obviously a shareable

Comment: If the voucher is shareable, then you'll have multiple people logged in at the same time as the same user potentially which is a security nightmare. I would use the voucher for on-boarding to create a real true user. That is a very common pattern for user-management. Whatever the voucher/product represents, you can store that in the user's meta for however it is needed.